# Display specific thumbnail content when clicked

Tags: jquery, html

I am facing a problem, every time I click on a thumbnail, it will display me content but it will display me double in this case, or in my original project 6 times. I managed to make project title read to work, but I struggle with displaying project description that is in .project[x] and display it only once, now it gives me a spinner and project title 2 times(or 6 in original version). I figured out though that the problem is in my work-wrap section, but I can't identify or fix this problem, yet.

After messing up more with the html markup and JS I ended up with this, I believe this is closer to my solution. Now it displays only 1 name (correctly for each thumbnail) and each thumbnail shows all classes (spinner/project1/project2)

example when clicked on first thumbnail: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtetu.png

HTML markup:

```
    <div class="work-belt">
        <div class="thumb-wrap">
            <div class="thumb-container">
                <a href="#/" class="thumb-unit">
                    <div data-class="project1" class="thumb-overlay">
                        <strong>Name1</strong>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a href="#/" class="thumb-unit">
                    <div data-class="project2" class="thumb-overlay">
                        <strong>Name2</strong>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="work-wrap">
            <div class="work-container">
                <h4 class="project-title"></h4>
                <div class="project-load"></div>
                <div class="project1">
                    <div style="width: 600px; height: 500px; background: #aaa;"></div>
                    <p>1st description</p>
                </div>
                <div class="project2">
                    <div style="width: 600px; height: 500px; background: #000;"></div>
                    <p>2nd description</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div> <!-- Ending of work-belt -->
```

JS markup:

function workLoad() {

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

$('.thumb-overlay').click(function() {

    var $this = $(this), 
            newTitle = $this.find('strong').text(),
            newClass = $this.data('class'),
            spinner = '<div class="loader">Loading...</div>',
            newWork = '<div class="project-load">'+ newClass +'</div>';
    $('.project-load').html(spinner).load(newWork);
    $('.project-title').text(newTitle);

});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML contains two div's with `class = "project-load"`. Remove whichever you don't want.

jQuery is changing every $('.project-load') it can find.

Comment: Yes, I see that mistake now, but then again after removing and leaving only one project-load class I am ending up with again same situation only slightly different. Leaving project-load class in the first  work-container div gives me first project div as a spinner and the next project class displaying the content of the  second thumbnail inside the work-wrap class..

Comment: Can you update the code in the question to match what you changed?

Comment: I updated the code and attached an image to maybe better understand my description. So as of now I see two problems here. Exact thumbnail content cannot pass the spinner phase and second problem it displays all work-containers when it should display only 1 in ideal situation.

Comment: To add up more: every thumbnail performs same action, first work-container displayed as spinner class and second class as project2. 
To be more clear no matter what thumbnail I press I get the same outcome as in the shared image.

Answer (score 0):

So I was provided with an answer to my solution. Turns out to be I did not even needed a spinner (stupid me) since it is obvious that you do not need it if information is injected directly. Secondly I had to make all project divs hidden in my SASS which I skipped in the beginning, so:

```
  SASS: 
    [class^='projectc']
      display: none
```

<-- NOTE in my case I had to change data attribute name and rename project divs so that the title would be unaffected -->

```
 <a href="#/" id="1" class="thumb-unit">
   <div data-class="projectc1" class="thumb-overlay">
     <strong>Name1</strong>
  </div>
</a>
<a href="#/" id="2" class="thumb-unit">
  <div data-class="projectc2" class="thumb-overlay">
    <strong>Name2</strong>
  </div>
</a>
```

...

```
   <h4 class="project-title"></h4>
     <!— <div class="project-load"></div> — Remove -->
     <div class="projectc1">
       <div style="width: 600px; height: 500px; background: #aaa;"></div>
       <p>1st description</p>
     </div>
```

js:

```
function workLoad() {

  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

  $('.thumb-overlay').click(function() {

    var $this = $(this), 
        newTitle = $this.find('strong').text(),
        newClass = $this.data('class');
     // $('.project-load').load(newClass);  -- Remove
     $("[class^='projectc']").css('display', 'none');
     $(newClass).css('display', 'block');
     $('.project-title').text(newTitle);

});
}
```